# Need specific domain name when hosting node app for Xbox over intranet

Tags: node.js, iis, intranet

I have a local network I set up with my Xbox and PC. The PC is running Windows 10 and currently acting as the router (Internet Connection Sharing with the Xbox through a switch). On my PC, I have a node server running to host the application that drives a dev UWP app on the Xbox.

I have tested all the connections. The Xbox can talk with my computer and v.v and my other computer can pull up the application hosted by the node server. The only problem is that anything connected to this network can only access the node app using the IP address of the my PC.

This is problematic for a variety of reasons, but mostly because of CORS and the fact that the UWP app requires pointing to the node app using a specific domain on the local network.

Now, if I could somehow just pull up the hosts file on the Xbox and modify that, then my problem would be solved. However, that does not seem possible. On the other hand, I could set up a site in IIS, but the files are hosted virtually by the node app and so there is no physical path to set.

What I need to do is somehow map the IP http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/ => http://myurl/ on the local network.

Comment: A DNS server is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be much easier than I anticipated. All I had to do *was* to modify the host file.

Initially, I had one entry in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
```

So, I added a second entry that points it to the IP address the clients have for my computer:

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
192.168.137.1 mydomain.com
```

Because ICS is on, the clients already have my PC set as the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the PC as a DNS server and point the XBOX to the PC for DNS services. Add an entry for your app in the DNS server with the PC's IP address as the IP and make sure to forward all other requests out a real DNS server.

Comment: That part I get. Because I have ICS turned on, the Xbox has my laptop's IP listed as the DNS, but I'm not sure how to configure my PC as an actual DNS server. I already tried modifying the hosts file to give a name to the address where I am locally serving the node app. This works on local, of course; I can throw the domain into my browser and it points to the node app. However, on the side of the XBOX, this does not work. It seems I have to use the IP address with the port for it to see the node app.

Comment: You will need to install DNS server software on your PC. Windows Server OSes have a built in feature to do so. Windows 10 does not. You will need to download and configure something like BIND. It's possible your router/modem may also support similar functionality. In either case you will add the entry to that DNS server configuration (rather than your hosts file).

Comment: I am trying out BIND right now... my anti-virus hates the installer though. lol

Comment: I figured it out.